# Regex for allowing Numeric, alphabet, hyphen(-) space and apostrophes(')

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, validation, user-interface

Currently I have a textbox that accepts only Alphabet, hyphens(-), space and apostrophes('). Now I would like to add numeric values as well to it. Currently I am using the Regex as below:

`/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ' -]+$/`

How would I achieve adding numerics as well to the above?

Answer (score 0):

To allow numbers, simply add `0-9` in your regex, like so:

`/^[0-9a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ' -]+$/`